# load html before asking for user's input using prompt.

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load html before asking for user's input using prompt(). html loads only when i quit the prompt. Please look at my code.

I have tried linking the javascript in the end of html body code but still html code do not loads before asking for input in prompt.

Here is html code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="third.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>new - To add new Todo</li>
        <li>list - To list all Todo on Console</li>
        <li>quit - To quit the Todo App</li>
        <li>delete - To remove an item from Todo App</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript code:-

```
var ansa = [];
var ans = prompt("What would you Like to do??");
while(ans !== "quit"){
    if(ans === "new"){
        addTodo();
    } else if (ans === "list") {
        listTodo();
    } else if (ans === "delete") {
        deleteTodo();
    };
    var ans = prompt("What would you Like to do??");
}

alert("Visit Agaain!!");

function addTodo () {
    var newTodo = prompt("Enter a new Todo!!!")
    ansa.push(newTodo);
    console.log(newTodo + " is added to the Todo")
}

function listTodo () {
    // console.log(ansa);
    console.log("***********");
    ansa.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(ansa.indexOf(item) + ": " + item)
        // console.log(index + ": " + item)
    })
    console.log("***********");
}

function deleteTodo () {
    var index = prompt("Which index would like to delete")
    ansa.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("Todo Item deleted")
}
```

Comment: run your code in `window.onload` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you run your code in a `window.onload` callback, it won't work. For some reason, that's how the browsers work.

If I'm not wrong, it works as you'd expect only on Internet Explorer.

The workaround I've always used in this case was to add a short timeout:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  // your code
}, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout and add the delay, please check the below code !

```
var ansa = [];
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  var ans = prompt("What would you Like to do??");
while(ans !== "quit"){
    if(ans === "new"){
        addTodo();
    } else if (ans === "list") {
        listTodo();
    } else if (ans === "delete") {
        deleteTodo();
    };
    var ans = prompt("What would you Like to do??");
}

alert("Visit Agaain!!");
}, delayInMilliseconds);



function addTodo () {
    var newTodo = prompt("Enter a new Todo!!!")
    ansa.push(newTodo);
    console.log(newTodo + " is added to the Todo")
}

function listTodo () {
    // console.log(ansa);
    console.log("***********");
    ansa.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(ansa.indexOf(item) + ": " + item)
        // console.log(index + ": " + item)
    })
    console.log("***********");
}

function deleteTodo () {
    var index = prompt("Which index would like to delete")
    ansa.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("Todo Item deleted")
}
```